# Dagger 2 Singleton between Android Activities

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am trying to understand how @Singleton works on Dagger 2

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.32'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.32'
```

Vehicle.kt

```
@Singleton
class Vehicle @Inject constructor() {

    var speed = 0
}
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component
interface AppComponent {

    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)

    fun inject(activity: SecondActivity)
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mVehicle: Vehicle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)

        mVehicle.speed = 75
    }
}
```

SecondActivity.kt

```
class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mVehicle: Vehicle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        DaggerAppComponent.create().inject(this)

        Log.d(TAG, "Vehicle speed: ${mVehicle.speed}")
    }
}
```

I expect to see the Vehicle speed 75 on SecondActivity, but it is 0. I am sure there must be something I am missing or misunderstand, just cannot figure it out.

Comment: i could be entirely wrong, but don't you have to make use of `@Provides` for something like this ?

Comment: My understanding for @Provides is to create an instance in @Module for class that does not have default constructor. The `Vehicle` class in my example has a default constructor so that I omit @Module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is based on the fact you're creating multiple instances of `DaggerAppComponent`. You have to create a component once, store it somewhere (`object`, `Application`), and then use it for injection. Every instance of the component represents a complete, independent dependency graph.

Something like this should work as expected:

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Component
interface AppComponent {
    fun inject(activity: FirstActivity)
    fun inject(activity: SecondActivity)
}

object ComponentHolder {
    val component: AppComponent by lazy { DaggerAppComponent.create() }
}

class FirstActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var mVehicle: Vehicle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ComponentHolder.component.inject(this)

        mVehicle.speed = 75
    }
}

class SecondActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var mVehicle: Vehicle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        ComponentHolder.component.inject(this)
        
        Log.d("SecondActivity", "Vehicle speed: ${mVehicle.speed}")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it works as expected. However, another question, since `AppComponent` is annotated with @Singleton, why is it created multiple times when calling `create()`? The library could handle it properly just like when we implement our own singleton pattern with function like `newInstance()`.

Comment: Scope annotation at `Component` class tells: "Lifetime of classes provided with scope X is tight to component with scope X". That's it. No more logic. You have to abstract yourself a bit from name @Singleton. You can create you custom scope, assign it to top level component and it definitely doesn't have to semantics "only one instance" per lifetime of an application.

Comment: I will have to spend some time to understand scope in Dagger. Again, thank you for help.

Comment: I recommend you to start here https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/dagger-android.

Comment: Thx for the link. I read the page before, and wondered why a subclass of Application was needed at that time. I know why now because `@Component` will only be created once just like you mentioned.